# Can I create a VarArray OleVariant from a buffer (pByte) and size without copying?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, safearray

I can copy the memory from the buffer into the safe array as follows

```
  function GetVarArrayFromBuffer(ABuffer : pByte; ASizeInBytes: Cardinal) : OleVariant;
  var
    LVarArrayPtr: Pointer;     
  begin
    Result := VarArrayCreate([0, ASizeInBytes - 1], varByte);
    LVarArrayPtr := VarArrayLock(Result);
    try
      Move(ABuffer^, LVarArrayPtr^, ASizeInBytes);
    finally
      VarArrayUnLock(Result);
    end;
  end;
```

But, is there a way to directly pass my pointer and size into a `varArray` type `OleVariant` without copying memory?

[Edit]

I can see that the array inside the `OleVariant` is a `SAFEARRAY` (defined as `PVarArray = ^TVarArray`), so it seems like there should be a way to do this by populating the values in a `TVarArray` and setting the `VType` and `VArray` values in the `OleVariant`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a way to directly pass my pointer and size into a varArray type OleVariant without copying memory?

Delphi's [`OleVariant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.OleVariant) type is a wrapper for OLE's [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627.aspx) record. The only type of array that OLE supports is [`SAFEARRAY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482.aspx), and any `SAFEARRAY` created by a Win32 `SafeArrayCreate...()` function allocates and owns the data block that it points to.  You have to copy your source data into that block.

To bypass that, you would have to skip `VarArrayCreate()` (which calls `SafeArrayCreate()`) and allocate the `SAFEARRAY` yourself using `SafeArrayAllocDescriptor/Ex()` so it does not allocate a data block.  Then you can set the array's `pvData` field to point at your existing memory block, and enable the `FADF_AUTO` flag in its `fFeatures` field to tell `SafeArrayDestroy()` (which `OleVariant` calls when it does not need the `SAFEARRAY` anymore) to not free your memory block.

Try something like this:

```
uses
  ..., Ole2, ComObj;

// Delphi's Ole2 unit declares SafeArrayAllocDescriptor()
// but does not declare SafeArrayAllocDescriptorEx()...
function SafeArrayAllocDescriptorEx(vt: TVarType; cDims: Integer; var psaOut: PSafeArray): HResult; stdcall; external 'oleaut32.dll';

function GetVarArrayFromBuffer(ABuffer : pByte; ASizeInBytes: Cardinal) : OleVariant;
var
  SA: PSafeArray;
begin
  OleCheck(SafeArrayAllocDescriptorEx(VT_UI1, 1, SA)); 

  SA.fFeatures := SA.fFeatures or FADF_AUTO or FADF_FIXEDSIZE;
  SA.cbElements := SizeOf(Byte);
  SA.pvData := ABuffer;
  SA.rgsabound[0].lLbound := 0;
  SA.rgsabound[0].cElements := ASizeInBytes;

  TVarData(Result).VType := varByte or varArray;
  TVarData(Result).VArray := PVarArray(SA);
end;
```

If you don't actually need to use OLE, such as if you are not passing your array to other people's applications via OLE, then you should use Delphi's [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant) type instead.  You can write a [`Custom Variant Type`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Defining_Custom_Variants_Index) to hold whatever data you want, even a reference to your existing memory block, and then use `Variant` as needed and let your custom type implementation manage the data as needed.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to hack your way into having an OleVariant with your array data in it without copying it.

However, a problem you are going to have is when the OleVariant variable falls out of scope.

The RTL is going to call SafeArrayDestroy in oleaut32.dll to destroy the memory associated with the safe array, and that's going to fail because the memory did not come from where Windows expected.

Comment: You can let Windows allocate the memory for the `SAFEARRAY` itself so `SafeArrayDestroy()` can free it, while still being able to make the `SAFEARRAY` point at a user-defined element block instead of allocating its own. The trick is to use `SafeArrayAllocDescriptor/Ex()` instead of `SafeArrayCreate()` (which VarArrayCreate()` uses), and then modify the SAFEARRAY's `fFeatures` field directly to tell `SafeArrayDestroy()` not to free the element block.